# How can I use CreateJS's PreloadJS to load images and retain attributes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, createjs, preloadjs

I am trying to preload images with CreateJS/PreloadJS. These images will replace an image with attributes like id and class. When I use JQuery to replace the image, all of these attributes are lost.

What is the proper way to preload images and then later display the images on my page?

```
<html>
    <img id="main" class="fit center"/>
</html>

function changeImage(event){
    $('#main').replaceWith(queue.getResult("main"));
}

function handleFileComplete(event){
    console.log(event.result);
}

function loadImage() { // jshint ignore:line
    var preload = new createjs.LoadQueue(); // jshint ignore:line
    preload.addEventListener("fileload", handleFileComplete);
    preload.loadFile("img/main.png");
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    queue = new createjs.LoadQueue();
    queue.loadManifest([
        {id: "main", src:"img/main.png"}
    ]);
    queue.on("complete", handleFileComplete, this);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply the attributes to the new image before using JQuery to replace the element.

```
var newImage = queue.getResult(label);
newImage.setAttribute("class", "fit center");
newImage.setAttribute("id", "main");
$('#main').replaceWith(newImage);
```